# Not visible @interface for 'MyController' declares the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning iOS development and I found an app source sample in the internet.
I'm trying to rewrite it and use it for tabbed layout, and after copying the `AppDelegate.m` from the sample app, I got the following error:

> No Visible @interface for 'FirstViewController' declares the selector alloc

In the following line:

```
FirstViewController *FirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
```

This is my full AppDelegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirstViewController *FirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:FirstViewController];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

same error (with `selector InithWithNibName:bundle`) in my `FirstViewController.m` file

```
MyViewController* MyController  = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

I don't know what this error means.

Comment: Can you include code for FirstViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use different names for your variables and classes.

change:

```
FirstViewController *FirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
```

to:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Cool, it was the problem. Thank you!